# Minimization Problem involving PCA

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, matrix-calculus

Starting from this equation to estimate:
$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Trace}$
$$ X = F^k \Lambda' ^ {k} + e, $$

with $ X$ an $T\times N $ matrix,  $ F$ is $T\times k $  and $ \Lambda$ is $k\times k $, I need to show that the solution to this problem:

$$\min _ { \Lambda ^ { k }} S ( k ) , \quad \text { with } \quad S ( k ) = ( N T ) ^ { - 1 } \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { N } \sum _ { t = 1 } ^ { T } \left( x _ { i t } - \lambda _ { i } ^ { k \prime } F _ { t } ^ { k } \right) ^ { 2 },$$

whit the constraint that $F ^ { k \prime } F ^ { k } / T = I _ { k } $ and 
$\Lambda ^ { k \prime } \Lambda ^ { k } $ is diagonal, is:

$ F^k = \sqrt{T}\times \text{Eigenvectors of k largest eigenvalues of X'X}$ and
$ \Lambda^k = F ^ { k \prime } X / T,$ that is a scaled version of the Principal Component estimator.

I procedeed in this way, starting from the first component:

\begin{align}
\min_{\lambda^ { 1 }} \ \ &( N T ) ^ { - 1 } \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { N } \sum _ { t = 1 } ^ { T } \left( x _ { i t } - \lambda _ { i } ^ { 1 \prime } F _ { t } ^ { 1 } \right) ^ { 2 } ,(\text{dropping the superscript 1 from now on)} = \\
&  (N T ) ^ { - 1 } \tr[(X - F\lambda')'(X-F\lambda')]  =\\
&  (N T ) ^ { - 1 } \tr(X'X) +  (N T ) ^ { - 1 }2F'X\lambda + (N) ^ { - 1 }\lambda'\lambda,
\end{align}

so that

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial\lambda} = 0 \iff& -2X'F/NT = 2\lambda /N \\
&\lambda = X'F/T.
\end{align}

However, once I substitute this back I arrive to maximize:
$$ (N T^2 ) ^ { - 1 } F^1XX'F^1, $$
and something seems off, since:

$$\max _ { F ^ { 1 }} \quad (N T^2 ) ^ { - 1 } F^1XX'F^1 \quad s.t. \ \ F'^1F^1 = T
$$

does not lead to finding the first eigenvalues of $ XX'$ and $ F^1 = \sqrt{T}\times \text{Eigenvectors of 1 largest eigenvalue}$ as it shold be.

I suspect I am doing something wrong with the Trace operatore, as I am not really familiar with it.